# form_with producing wrong controller (only on some routes)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-with

This is in `application.html.erb`, and it works on 95% of the pages in my app:

```
<% ['usd', 'eur', 'aud'].each do |currency| %>

  <%= form_with url: {controller: :home, action: :currency_select}, method: :post do |currency_form| %>
    <%= currency_form.hidden_field :preferred_display_currency, value: currency %>
    <%= currency_form.submit currency, class: "btn-info shadow-none" %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

But when I visit a certain view, before the page even loads, it gives this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"currency_select", :controller=>"users/home"}):
    191:                  
    192:                     <%= form_with url: {controller: :home, action: :currency_select}, method: :post do |currency_form| %>
    193:                       <%= currency_form.hidden_field :preferred_display_currency, value: currency %>
    194:                       <%= currency_form.submit currency, class: "btn-info shadow-none" %>
    195:                     <% end %>
    196: 
    197:                   <% end %>
```

I'm pretty sure something to do with `:controller=>"users/home"` (where it should simply be `:controller=>"home"`)

Why is the form suddenly confused about the controller?

Comment: check your routes.rb

Comment: @togi I have `devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }` based on instructions [here](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#configuring-controllers). Do you think that's part of the problem?

Comment: @togi I could be wrong, but I don't think `routes.rb` is the problem. I think the form is auto generating the wrong controller for some reason. I.e. it should be generating `controller: "home"` but instead it's generating `controller: "users/home"`, and I don't understand why it's doing that

Comment: where is your controller? is it in 'users' folder ?

Comment: @togi the `/controllers/home_controller.rb` is where the home controller is located, and there's also `/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb`

Comment: are you getting the error when load registration page?

Comment: @togi yep. It seems to work on every other page I try (including many other controllers). But not for views that go to the registrations_controller.rb

Comment: how about 
```
<% if current_user %>
<% ['usd', 'eur', 'aud'].each do |currency| %>

  <%= form_with url: {controller: :home, action: :currency_select}, method: :post do |currency_form| %>
    <%= currency_form.hidden_field :preferred_display_currency, value: currency %>
    <%= currency_form.submit currency, class: "btn-info shadow-none" %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
<% end %>

``` ?

Comment: @togi unfortunately that's not it (it's already wrapped in `if user_signed_in?`. I tried anyway, and get the same error

Comment: @togi I didn't find a solution, but I made a work around: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67965563/5783745

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1

Run

```
rails routes | grep currency
```

it returns

```
currency_select POST   /currency_select(.:format)  
 home#currency_select
```

Now just use `url: currency_select_path` like so:

```
<% ['usd', 'eur', 'aud'].each do |currency| %>

  <%= form_with url: currency_select_path, method: :post do |currency_form| %>
    <%= currency_form.hidden_field :preferred_display_currency, value: currency %>
    <%= currency_form.submit currency, class: "btn-info shadow-none" %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

#### Solution 2

Replace `:home` with `"/home"`:

```
<% ['usd', 'eur', 'aud'].each do |currency| %>

  <%= form_with url: {controller: "/home", action: :currency_select}, method: :post do |currency_form| %>
    <%= currency_form.hidden_field :preferred_display_currency, value: currency %>
    <%= currency_form.submit currency, class: "btn-info shadow-none" %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

(not totally sure why that works, but can confirm that it indeed works!)

#### A work around

The above two solutions are best, but a work around for the problem could be:

```
<% if !current_page?(edit_user_registration_path) %>
# all existing code
<% end %>
```

This way it simply avoids displaying the form on the route that errors. It's not ideal, but a practical work around.

Comment: It works probably because of name-spacing issues when using `:home`, this is not intuitive behavior with Rails I must say.

Comment: @Eyeslandic was it a bad idea to name a controller home? (it's where I keep static pages, like /about, /terms, and a few other orphan routes)

Comment: No, not at all, I don't see any problem with it.